# PHP checking for NULL value

Tags: php

Just out of curiosity (and a bit of necessity):

```
if(! is_null($var)){
     //do something
}
```

Is the above statement the same as

```
if($var != NULL){
//do something
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What are your own conclusions? Do you have any specific reason for your suspicions?

Comment: Yes, they are. Look at the php comparision table: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: I have, the above statement seems to evaluate to true regardless if the var is NULL or not. Seems to me it shouldnt be this way

Comment: There is a difference though. The last one doesnt use a function, which might have influence on the memory used. But not in an amount you should care about

Comment: Might depend on the way it's used. Even though you didn't add a `mysql` tag, are you using this for DB, or just PHP?

Comment: the $var will contain a mysql field value

Comment: Then that could be the issue. MySQL columns could contain empty columns, or can also be set to `NULL` or `NOT NULL`, so that could be a factor in this case. @Kisaragi - Your question should have contained the `mysql` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are not the same.

The `is_null` function compairs the type also.

Example:

```php
var_dump(is_null(0)); // bool(false) 
var_dump(0 == NULL);  // bool(true) 
var_dump(0 === NULL); // bool(false)
```

So in your case

```
if(! is_null($var)){
     //do something
}
```

Would be the same as

```
if($var !== NULL){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is (almost) correct, you can test this yourself:

```
    $emptyvar1 = null;
    $emptyvar2="";
    if(is_null($emptyvar1) && $emptyvar1 == NULL){
        echo "1";
    }
    if(is_null($emptyvar2)){
        echo "2";
    }
    if($emptyvar2 == null){
        echo "3";
    }
    if($emptyvar2 === null){
        echo "4";
    }
```

This will print 1 and 3.
because an empty string is equal to null if you only use 2 times =
if you use 3 times = it aint.

=== also checks object type
== only checks value

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're testing, but on:

a) $var = NULL;
neither of the statements triggers,

b) $var = 0;
is_null triggers and

c) $var = ''; is_null triggers aswell.

So the statements above are definitely not coming to the same conclusion.

See for yourself:

```
echo 'testing NULL case<br>';
$var = NULL;
if(! is_null($var)){
    echo 'var is_null<br>';
}
if($var != NULL){
    echo 'var != null<br>';
}

echo 'testing 0 case<br>';
$var = 0;
if(! is_null($var)){
    echo 'var is_null<br>';
}
if($var != NULL){
    echo 'var != null<br>';
}

echo 'testing empty string case<br>';
$var = '';
if(! is_null($var)){
    echo 'var is_null<br>';
}
if($var != NULL){
    echo 'var != null<br>';
}
```

this outputs

```
testing NULL case
testing 0 case
var is_null
testing empty string case
var is_null
```